# CSV columns as single list instead of separated strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I'm trying to use the CSV module to put the contents of a CSV file into a list and then sort the list accordingly. The problem is that when I read the list it puts each column in its own list separated by a comma and a '\n'.

```
with open(filename) as file: 
        csv_file = file.readlines()
        print(csv_file)
```

yields:

```
['6,3,16,3\n', '11,7,7\n', '17,10,14\n', '8,5,19\n']
```

And any other way I've tried to put them into a list only yields me:

```
[[6, 3, 16, 3], [11, 7, 7], [17, 10, 14], [8, 5, 19]]
```

I just need one single editable list to work from but I can't get it to work in the way I'm wanting, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my first time working with CSV.

Comment: Could you share the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to use in Anaconda
  import pandas as pd
  csv_file=pd.read_csv('file_path','encoding=UTF-8')
  csv_file